# Google App Engine streaming data into Bigquery: GCP architecture

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm working with a Django web app deployed on Google App Engine flexible environment.
I'm streaming my data while processing requests in my views using bigquery.Client(). But I think it is not the best way to do it. Do I need to delegate this process outside of the view (using pub/sub, tasks, cloud functions etc.? If so, give me a suitable architecture: which GCP product should I use, how to connect, and what to read.

Comment: What is your data source? A file? PubSub? what's the volume? the frequency? the latency (between the event generation and BigQuery integration)??

Comment: What is your data source? The data is based on a request (JSON data from POST request).
What's the volume? From 1 to 5000 rows x 20 columns (pricelists). In case of 5k rows it takes around 1-3 seconds before response, but I want to send the response as soon as possible (without waiting for Bigquery streaming). I do not know GCP products well enough, so I may misunderstand something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, I could recommend you Cloud Run;

Cloud Run is a serverless container based product. You write a webserver (that handle your POST request), wrap it in a container and deploy it on Cloud Run.

With a brand new feature, named [always on](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation) the CPU is not throttled after the response sent (the normal behavior). With always on, you keep the full CPU up to the Cloud Run instances off load (usually after 15 minutes, but can be quicker).

The benefit of the feature is the capacity to return immediately the response to the client, and then to continue to process, asynchronously, your data to store in BigQuery (in streaming mode).